# Access a button from the form in other class in C#

Tags: c#

I want to know if a button is pressed in C# from another class. I have my standard class Form and another class Device. Now I want to access the button from InitializeComponent in Form in my class Device. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

EDIT: If I press on the btnInitialise I want to show a messagebox (with text "test") to start with. I want to use this button in the class Device. I don't rely know how I can reference the button btnInitialise that is automatically made in my form to the class Device.

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

    #region "Windows Form Designer generated code"

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.btnInitialise = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmbdevice = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(42, 41);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(645, 414);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.grpDevice);
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(637, 388);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        //
        // btnInitialise
        // 
        this.btnInitialise.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(351, 16);
        this.btnInitialise.Name = "btnInitialise";
        this.btnInitialise.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 25);
        this.btnInitialise.TabIndex = 21;
        this.btnInitialise.Text = "Initialize";
        this.btnInitialise.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnInitialise_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1005, 532);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpDevice.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpDevice.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private TabControl tabControl1;
    private TabPage tabPage1;
    private Button btnInitialise;

    #endregion "Windows Form Designer generated code"

    #region "Global variables"
    // OpenLayers fields
    ////Encapsulates a DT-open layers deviceand manages and distributes subsystems for the device
    private Device device = null;



    #endregion "Global variables"


    //Automatically to initialize components of form
    public Form1()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        //Set the culture to en-US for decimal point instead of decimal comma in results
        CultureInfo english = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = english;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (device != null)
            {
                device.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    //Run application, show error message if appl doesnt run
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }
}


public class Device
{
    //When clicking on the initialize button show messagebox 
    private void btnInitialise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show what you tried already

Comment: If you have a reference to an instance of an object (say a form class) in a method of another class (say a device), then you can access the public methods, properties and fields of that object.  The button is a property of the form, but it is typically a private property.  What do you really want to do?  What have you tried?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please provide your code to us.

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the button to other classes. One way to do so would be using public property. e.g.

```
 public Button MyButton
 {
   get { return button1; }
 }
```

then from the Form class you can use it as

```
Device d = new Device();
Button b = d.MyButton;
```

Note: This example is based on what you have asked in the post. However, it is not clear what are you actually going to achieve by getting a button like this! If you add a code sample and more info about the application you are developing we can help you better.

Comment: He needs the opposite - acessing the button which is in `Form` from `Device`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Form` constructor should look like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    //
    // Required for Windows Form Designer support
    //
    InitializeComponent();
    //Set the culture to en-US for decimal point instead of decimal comma in results
    CultureInfo english = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = english;
    device = new Device();
    this.btnInitialise.Click += new System.EventHandler(device.btnInitialise_Click);
}
```

Now in `Device` you should make the eventhandler `public`, like this:

```
public class Device
{
    //When clicking on the initialize button show messagebox 
    public void btnInitialise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

Now the `Device's btnInitialise_Click` method will be triggered when you click the button.

**Edit**: Fixed typo in `Device`, try Again.

Comment: If I do this I get 2 errors In form1: 
First one: Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'deviceName' of 'Device.Device(string)'
Second one: Error CS1061 'Device' does not contain a definition for 'btnInitialise_Click' and no accessible extension method 'btnInitialise_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'Device' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
It's a error of the 2 lines in Form:
device = new Device();
this.btnInitialise.Click += new System.EventHandler(device.btnInitialise_Click);